# setting global variables bottle

Tags: python, global-variables, bottle

I am trying to save some variables to global variable but in another function I am getting an empty dict.

Line 59 - 192.168.204.169
{'uid': ['{14EEFF8F-E469-C174-8906-AE36EBF5CD94}'], 'device': '35'}

Line 87 - Selected rules are {}

```
_local_bottle = bottle.Bottle()
devices = {}
selected = {}


def get_bottle():
    return _local_bottle

@_local_bottle.route(base_url_path, method='POST')
def sending_exception_api_call():
    global selected
    postdata = bottle.request.body.read()
    host = bottle.request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST')
    logger.info("Sending the API exception request")
    selected = json.loads(postdata)
    logger.info("{}\n{}".format(host, selected))
    devices_dict = {device.id: device.name for device in devices}
    logger.info("devices: {}".format(devices_dict))

@_local_bottle.route(base_url_path+'/exception_form', method="POST")
def get_info_for_exception_request():
    global selected
    logger.info("Sending the exception API request")
    logger.info(bottle.request.body.read())
    postdata = str(bottle.request.body.read()).split('&')
    requester = postdata[0].split('=')
    approver = postdata[1].split('=')
    expiration_date = postdata[2].split('=')
    logger.info("Got the following fields. requester: {}, approver: {}, expiration_date: {}".format(requester[1],                                                                                               approver[1],
                                                                                                    expiration_date[1]))
    logger.info("Selected rules are {}".format(selected))
    rules = get_rules(selected['device'])
    logger.info('Rules are {}'.format(rules))
```

Comment: inside both function in first line write global nameOfGlobalVarible

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

Comment: Confusing since in get_info_for_exception_request you never assign selected only reference it so it should be considered global per `"In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as global"`.

Comment: When you want to edit a global variable, you need the global statement. Otherwise you can just get it.

Comment: I have changed the code according to your suggestions, but I am getting the same result. I don't think it's a python issue, but a server issue.

Comment: often servers run every client or even every requests in separated thread and use separted variables - so next request doesn't have access to previous content. Better save it in database.